# How do I highlight ng-repeat items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I highlight the newest item added to a list that is displayed with ng-repeat? I've tried using jquery `effect()` in my `addItem()` function but that didn't work. I've also tried using the highlight filter from angular-ui without success.

```
//controller
$scope.addItem = function() {
  $scope.items.unshift($scope.item);
};

//html
<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media" ng-repeat="item in items | highlight:item">
```

Comment: How do you want to highlight them?

Comment: Angular.js 1.1.4 has added support for animations that run when items are added or removed from ng-repeats: http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/04/angularjs-106-universal-irreversibility.html

Comment: @JosephSilber Just the standard jquery highlight effect

Comment: @KarlZilles I just discovered the animation stuff and am currently working on a fiddle. I think it will end up working for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Angular has been supporting animations since version 1.1.4](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/04/angularjs-106-universal-irreversibility.html).

Just add `ng-animate` to you `li`s, with an animation name:

```html
<li ng-animate="'highlight'" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
```

and supply the proper animation CSS for that animation name:

```css
li {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s 1.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}

.highlight-enter-setup {
    background: yellow;
}
.highlight-enter-start {
    background: white;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4Tnw/

---

You are not limited to just highlighting. You can do all sorts of crazy animations.

Here's a crazier example: http://jsfiddle.net/u4Tnw/3/

Comment: Note that the ng-animate attribute is deprecated in 1.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394017/angularjs-1-2-nganimate-not-working for more info.